# How to output php search result to html table?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Want to output search result from database into an html table, but all I'm getting is a printed array. Fairly certain that's due to "print_r", but how do I output to html table instead and getting shown more than just the first result?

My html table using data from my database works fine - but there I'm just using a "SELECT *" with no user input.

I've tried playing around with my php-code that works with just the "SELECT *", but no luck.

```
<?php


$servername = "test";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";
$dbname = "test";

$journal      = (isset($_SESSION["journal"]))      ? $_SESSION["journal"]      
: null;  

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname) or die("something went wrong");

if(isset($_POST["form_submit"]))
{
    $journal =$_POST["journal"];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM straffesager WHERE journalnummer=?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s",$journal);

        $stmt->execute();
    $val = $stmt->get_result();
    $row_count= $val->num_rows;

    if($row_count >0)
    {
        $result =$val->fetch_assoc();

        print_r($result);
            }
    else{
        echo "<br><br>Den indtastede information matcher ikke sager i databasen.";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

}

?>
```

This is my result: "Array ( [idnumber] => 4 [journalnummer] => 17-1717171 [status] => lukket".

The result above is just text. I'd like it to be in the html table I'm using somewhere else as well.

How do I output the result from my code to an HTML table and have more than one search result being shown?

Thanks for helping out a rookie.

Comment: First of all, you're just dumping your result to your screen with print_r. To show it in an html table you need to actually create an html table.. Inside your html table loop over your $result with an Foreach for example. Then just echo a <tr> with the contents of $result in it. PHP doesn't magically create HTML tables for you.

Comment: so instead of print_r, I should use echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```php
$result =$val->fetch_assoc();
print_r($result);
```

you should print your table with help of your `$result` variable
like this

```php
echo "<table><tr><th>HEAD1</th><th>HEAD2</th><th>HEAD3</th></tr>";
while ($row = $val->fetch_assoc()) {
   printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",
       $row['idnumber'],$row['journalnummer'],$row['status']);
       //it will put $row instead of %s
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This half-works; I'm getting the data outputted into a table, but with no headers for each column. If I input <th>column name</th><td>%s</td> then the header name with be positioned in front of the data, not above. 

Any way to fix this?

Comment: replace HEAD1,2,3 with what you want

Comment: holy heck - this actually worked, but only for the first search result?